# Como recuperar objeto pela URI passando parâmetro e mostrando Status da requisição

Tags: spring, postman

Tô aprendendo a trabalhar com Spring REST, já consigo recuperar objeto pelo URL no postman, mas na minha URL se eu passar um parâmetro ex: http://localhost:8080/categorias/50 Ele mostra como status 200 OK se achou ou não, mas queria que mostra-se 404 senão encontra-se, cheguei a ver alguns exemplos mas o exemplo que eu peguei não deu Certo.

*meu Codigo

```
@RequestMapping("/categorias")
public class CategoriaResource {


@Autowired 
    private CategoriasRepository categoriasRepository;


@GetMapping("/{codigo}")
public Optional<Categoria> buscarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable Long codigo) {
    
    
     return categoriasRepository.findById(codigo);
}

Exemplo que encontrei na internet; Não consigo utilizar o metodo findOne, ele pede para o retorno do meu método seja, Optional

@GetMapping("/{codigo}")
public ResponseEntity<Categoria> buscarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable Long codigo) {
     Categoria categoria = categoriaRepository.findOne(codigo);
     return categoria != null ? ResponseEntity.ok(categoria) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dayson, verifica se esse formato te ajuda:

```
if (categoria == null) {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
return new ResponseEntity(categoria, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideal é colocar essa logica dentro de um serviço, por exemplo:

```
if(categoria == null){
  trown new NotFoundError("Categoria não encontrada)
}
//exemplo de classe NotFound
public class NotFoundError extends Exception {
    
    public NotFoundError(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```